# Auto/cross correlation for data set with multiple realizations

Tags: autocorrelation, cross-correlation, correlation

**Context**

For an assignment, I need to find the correlation matrix of a dataset with 100 random variables and 1000 realizations for each. (It's a stock market example).

**Problem**

I don't understand how one can compute the auto/cross-correlation for a given dataset of discrete random variables with multiple realizations.

**Example**

If $x(n)$ is a random variable with three realizations. E.g. (some example I came up with):

$x(n) = \begin{Bmatrix} 2, & 1, & 3 \end{Bmatrix}$

Then how do you compute its autocorrelation $r_{xx}$?

I know that $r_{xx} = E[x(n)x^*(n-k)]$, which will result in a convolution function. I think it should be something like:

$\sum x(n)x(n-k) P(x=a_k,y=b_k)$ $\rightarrow$ $\frac{1}{N^2}\sum x(n)x(n-k)$

Because the probability of it having some set of values is $1/N^2 = 1/3^2$, I think.

However, I think this is completely wrong because this gives an array of values and I also tried computing a correlation matrix with $c_{xx} = r_{xx} - m_x^2$, and that gives different results.

I just really want to understand how it works, but I haven't been able to. I would really appreciate some help on this matter.

Thanks in advance!

**Better example to make my issue clearer**

Say $x(n) = \begin{Bmatrix} (n=0) & (n=1) & (n=2) & (n=3) \\ 2 & 1 & 3 & 4\\ 1 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\ 1 & 3 & 2 & 3  \end{Bmatrix}$

With the time index on the horizontal and the different realizations on the vertical. How does the autocorrelation computation process work?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about statistics, not about signal processing. I'd recommend migration to https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: (also, you're confusing "auto-/crosscorrelation", which is a property of a stochastic process as a whole, not of a realization, with "empiric correlation", which is computed on a set of given data points. That's the whole problem here.)

Comment: Correlation in this form does not seem to be a big concept in statistics, but it is commonly used in my Signal Processing course, so that's why I posted here.

Comment: it definitely is a big concept in statistics :)

Comment: From my understanding, in statistics they usually mean the correlation coefficient (normalized covariance) instead of $r_{xy} = E[XY]$. This part of signal processing is applied statistics, so I was hoping I could get the best help here.

Comment: That's nice and all, but there's no signal processing involved, but statistics. If you can even define that you care about $E[XY]$, then why shouldn't actual staticians have any problem understanding your question?

Comment: Hi: correlation is defined differently in digital signal processing versus statistics. There have been many DSP discussions on this in the past so I didn't want to go near this  question. If you want the statistical viewpoint, you can send to cross-validated. If you want the DSP viewpoint, stay here. Note that, your question is also difficult because you use the term autocorrelation a lot in your discussion which is a very different thing from normalized covariance. I have a feeling you mean normalized covariance which, in statistics, is referred to as correlation.

Comment: Hi, Mark. I get that there is a difference in the definitions. I mean $r_{xx} = E[x(k)x(l)]$, which should be the signal processing definition, as I understand it.

Comment: yes. and in statistics, what you wrote is defined as the covariance. note that auto-correlation is pretty different from correlation ( in statistics anyway. not sure about DSP ) because auto-correlation denotes how a stock's returns ( or prices or whatever one is considering ) is correlated with its own returns at different lags. correlation denotes how a stock's returns is correlated with a different stock's returns.  It sounds like you want the statistical version of correlation which is described in any decent statistics text. ( johnson and wichern for example ).

Comment: Hi Wirral: This goes through the painful manual  step by step for two stocks from the STATISTICAL viewpoint.  In your case, you have a lot more stocks so you'd of course want to use R or Python etc. https://www.dummies.com/education/math/business-statistics/how-to-measure-the-covariance-and-correlation-of-data-samples/